# java swing application installed over server

Tags: swing, network-programming

I have to develop an application which will run server and and access through Remote connection to multiple user, is normal application is accessible to multiple user at the same time or we have to make some effort .
We are thinking to use technologies are
1: java swing and hibernate for persistence layer , as its single desktop application , so does we need to add server to give access to multiple user at the same time.
Thanks in advance.